# Is there any Blazor timepicker and colorPicker?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is there any Blazor time picker and color picker?
I am looking for a color picker and time picker in blazor that supports most of the browsers with uniforms behavior. I am finding only HTML control which is not uniform across browsers.

Comment: Blazor uses the same web controls as other sites use as it can still run the normal HTML controls and javascript libraries, you can find any javascript library and use that with blazor using [`IJSRuntime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I think the Microsoft intentionally didn't add too much default components to the library: you now see that a new marketplace has emerged for Blazor components. You can always use stuff like `<input type="color"...` but it doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
Install-Package BlazorColorPicker
```

add script section to index.html or _Host.cshtml (head section)

```
<link href="_content/BlazorColorPicker/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="_content/BlazorColorPicker/colorpicker.js"></script>
```

Usage

```
@page "/"

@using BlazorColorPicker
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OpenModal">
    <div style="background-color:@color" class="buttonColor"></div> Select a Color
</button>

<ColorPicker Title="My Blazor ColorPicker" IsOpened="isOpened" Closed="ClosedEvent" MyColor="@color">
</ColorPicker>

@code {
    bool isOpened = false;
    string color = "#F1F7E9";

    void OpenModal()
    {
        isOpened = true;
    }

    void ClosedEvent(string value)
    {
        color = value;
        isOpened = false;
    }
}
```

[Project](https://github.com/tossnet/Blazor-Color-Picker)

[Or radzen](https://blazor.radzen.com/colorpicker)

```
<RadzenColorPicker @bind-Value=@color ShowHSV=@showHSV ShowRGBA=@showRGBA 
ShowColors=@showColors ShowButton=@showButton Change=@OnChange />


void OnChange(string value)
{
    console.Log($"Value changed to: {value}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a component to use in Blazor server for selecting the color. It uses the HTML input type color.

```
<input type="color" id="head" name="head" value="@InColor" @onchange="@UpdateIt">
<label for="head">@InColor</label>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string InColor { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ReturnedColor { get; set; }

    private void UpdateIt(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        InColor = e.Value.ToString();
        ReturnedColor.InvokeAsync(InColor);
    }

}
```

To use all you have to do is create a new blazor component and paste the entire code. For example I created a `ColorSelector.razor` file and to use in my project would be:

```
<ColorSelector InColor="@MyColor" ReturnedColor="ColorChange"></ColorSelector>
...
@code
{
    private void ColorChange(string e)
    {
        MyColor = e;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

You could do the same for a DatePicker or other already defined HTML components.

Comment: I created a github rep with a sample project for the Color Selector: [link](https://github.com/MarianoJP/ColorSelectionComponent)

Comment: I adjusted your solution with new answer, if you are not agree , I will delete it !

Answer (score 1):

I will adjust code of @Mariano to built-in blazor `InputText` and this way you will two way databinding and when click submit your `EditForm` will catch the change: 
**ColorSelector.razor**

```
<InputText type="color" id="head" name="head"
Value="@InColor"
ValueExpression="@(() => InColor)"
ValueChanged="@((string value) => UpdateIt(value))" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string InColor { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ReturnedColor { get; set; }

    private void UpdateIt(string value)
    {
        InColor = value;
        ReturnedColor.InvokeAsync(InColor);
    }

}
```

Then You can use it like this:

```
<ColorSelector InColor="@MyColor" ReturnedColor="ColorChange"></ColorSelector>
...
@code
{
    private void ColorChange(string e)
    {
        MyColor = e;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using value binding is value change handled by binding.

Component markup:

```
<input type="color" @bind-value="@ColorHexCode"/>
```

Component code:

```
public partial class ColorPicker : ComponentBase
{
    private string m_ColorHexCode;

    [Parameter]
    public string ColorHexCode
    {
        get => m_ColorHexCode;
        set
        {
            if (m_ColorHexCode == value) return;

            m_ColorHexCode = value;

            ColorHexCodeChanged.InvokeAsync(m_ColorHexCode);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ColorHexCodeChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Component usage:

```
<ColorPicker @bind-ColorHexCode="@ColorCode"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that shows how you could create a simple time picker:

https://github.com/pekspro/BlazorTimePicker

You could then use the time picker like this:

```
<Pekspro.Blazor.TimePicker.TimePickerComponent @bind-SecondOfDay="SecondOfDay" />
```

In the same project there is also a component date combines the time picker with a date picker that you easily could bind to a DateTime:

```
<Pekspro.Blazor.TimePicker.DateTimePickerComponent @bind-DateAndTime="SelectedDateTime" />
```

Answer (score -1):

As Umair mentioned, you can use any javascript library in the blazor app. As far as I know there aren't any default controls you mentioned in the blazor package. For the time picker I would recommend something out of javascript world, or you can use some of the **MatBlazor** library - for the timepicker you could use a datePicker with additional time to choose. For more information about **MatBlazor**, see [this](https://www.matblazor.com/DatePicker)

Comment: This is a Blazor question. Whilst Blazor can use JS components, to do so goes against the design goals of Blazor, which is to avoid writing JS where possible. So recommending OP uses a JS component isn't a useful answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd be careful with custom controls.  The browsers in some devices, especially phones, are supposed to be able to handle html controls like  however the want.  An iPhone user, for example, might be USED to inputting color with a particular control, and might not like you overriding the default.

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer. The OP didn't mention custom controls, just Blazor components that implement date/time pickers, so there's no reason to think they're going to build or use custom or non-standard controls. Blazor uses standard HTML controls anyway. It's fine to suggest a warning like this, but in the context of not actually providing suggestions that answer the question, it's not a particularly useful answer.